# shiny input doesn't work

Tags: html, r, shiny

I created a shiny app. with some select input.

**HTML code**:

```
    <label>1.  Choose industry:
    <select  style="background-color:#efeff0"  onclick="myFunction1(this.value)" name="vertical_id" id="vertical_id" class="selectized shiny-band-input" tabindex="-1">
    <option style="color:#800d7e"  name="vertical_id_name" value="Online">Online</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name"  value="Forex">Forex</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Binary Options">Binary Options</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Social Gaming">Social Gaming</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Finance">Finance</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Telecom">Telecom</option>
    <option  style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name" value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
    <option style="color:#800d7e" name="vertical_id_name"  value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
            <input style="visibility: hidden" style="background-color:#efeff0" type="text"  id="vertical_id_Others_text" />
    </label>
```

in R server i want to get the value that i choose in the UI.
so i write:

```
vertical_id<<-input$vertical_id
```

the variable vertical_id is always the same (he's value is: "Online"). it doesn't change.

what's wrong?

Comment: We would need to see more code here to be of use... any particular reason you're using global assignment (`<<-`) instead of assignment (`<-`)?

Comment: I use this assignment to see the variables value.

Comment: I can paste all code here. but this is very long code...

Answer (score 1):

make sure you define the data as reactive

e.g.

```
filteredStateData<-reactive({
    if(!(is.null(input$vertical_id) || input$vertical_id =="")) 
      return(yourdata[which...=input$vertical_id]   
    else
      return(yourdefaultdatawhennull)
  })
```